# Sqlalchemy: type object 'Users' has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I've been trying for a while to make this code work however my lack of knowledge about sqlalchemy keeps me from making it work.
It should check the username but it gives me an error, wonder if someone here could help me

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usrn = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        user = Users.query.filter_by(username=usrn).first()
        if user:
            /* CODE */
        else:
            /* CODE */
```

And this is the model:

```
engine = db.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://luca:luca@localhost/forum', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session=Session()
metadata = db.MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name',VARCHAR(25))
    surname = Column('surname',VARCHAR(25))
    username = Column('username',VARCHAR(20))
    mail = Column('mail',VARCHAR(50))
    password = Column('password',CHAR(32))
    role=Column('role',VARCHAR(10))
    threads = relationship("Threads")
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `session.query(Users).filter_by(...).first()`, as show [here](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mysql-python-sqlalchemy.rst#Update-MySQL-Data)?